# In ASP.Net Web API, how do you get LogonUserIdentity?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I can do this in ASP.Net MVC

```
 var userName = request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
```

How do I accomplish this in ASP.Net Web API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it often goes (at least with me), I spend an hour looking for an answer and then find it 2 minutes after posting a question on stack overflow. As it turns out, just go through HttpContext.Current.Request, instead of Request. In Web API, here's how it's done:

```
var userName = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name
```